# solving quadratic equations using machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, regression

I am attempting to solve quadratic equations using machine learning. I tried to write [code using mxnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401060/mxnet-regression-divide-by-zero-error) but fails because it is using linear regression while my problem is non-linear (as far as I know).

It is possible to predict the solution for arbitrary equations provided the at least one real root exists?

Comment: Could you give an example of the form that you receive the equation in? For instance are you receiving (x, y) data and want to fit a quadratic equation to it? Or are you receiving an equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$?

Comment: @NeilSlater The equation itself (i.e. your 2nd option). This is just for testing machine learning capablitity for predicting solutinos for such problem where the solution is unknown.

Comment: This should answer your question at least in part:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/331101795_Exploration_of_Machine_learning_for_Polynomial_Root_Finding_Motivation

Answer (score 2):

> It is possible to predict the solution for arbitrary equations provided the at least one real root exists?

Yes.

You‘ll just need a sufficiently large training dataset and network that is flexible enough (start with one hidden layer).

You’re right your problem is not linear, thus you’ll need non-linear activation function.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried many times to build a fully connected network without success getting even 0% accuracy on +100k dataset built using counter that evaluates in a quadratic equation.